# Filtering on a multiple word string in a field (elasticsearch 1.1)

Tags: elasticsearch

My json query:

```
{
   "size": 3,
   "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": { "term": { "publication_type": "horse mouth" }}
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to search for the two words "horse mouth" in the field publication_type?

Atm I can only get results when i search for "horse" or "mouth"..

Working with elasticsearch 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) filter for this. You can use execution mode to "and" if you want all the terms to be present in the document. The default is equivalent to an "or"

Example:

```
{
   "size": 3,
   "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": { "match_all": {} },
            "filter": { "terms": { "publication_type": ["horse", "mouth"]}}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Keety. It works indeed. Do you also know how to do this with elasticsearch aggregations? Right now its returns "horse" and "mouth" as seperate terms?